# Here Rest API: How to limit the suggestion result in an area?

Tags: here-api

I need Here map API to auto complete the address. I am trying to use Place suggestion API which is documented: https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/places-search/search-suggestion

However the API behavior surprises me. I was trying to get suggestion in Washington area with query "20" (a partial house number):

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Map-Viewport: -125.0061,45.6674,-120.6775,48.7269" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" "https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/suggest?q=20&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&size=5"

{
  "suggestions": [
    "205th Ave KP S, Lakebay, WA 98349, USA",
    "Mall 205",
    "204th Avenue KP S, Lakebay, WA 98349, USA",
    "202nd Avenue KP S, Lakebay, WA 98349, USA",
    "McMenamins"
  ]
}
```

This looks fine to me.

But what surprises me is when I start querying "2021", it's returning me addresses in Mexico:

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Map-Viewport: -125.0061,45.6674,-120.6775,48.7269" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" "https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/suggest?q=2021&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&size=10"

{
  "suggestions": [
    "2021 California",
    "20218, Aguascalientes, Mexico",
    "Taco Bell",
    "20219, Aguascalientes, Mexico",
    "2021 Restaurant",
    "20216, Aguascalientes, Mexico",
    "2021 Wireless",
    "20210, Aguascalientes, Mexico",
    "2021.Interactive, LLC",
    "20213, Peñas Blancas, Costa Rica"
  ]
}
```

I'd rather to get no result if it cannot find match in the area than getting results out of the bounding box.

**My question**: how can I actually limit the search area? Another question is how to filter out results which are not addresses?

Comment: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics/location-contexts.html is well documented for you

Comment: I have tried both Explicit Location Context and Implicit Location Context by setting "in" as query parameter and "X‑Map‑Viewport" as header in my example. Both requests return me Mexico addresses while I am asking for Washington area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is not yet possible to limit Places Suggest API results to a given country. You could try using explicit location contexts (`?in=[your-country-polygon]`) but then then you cannot use the implicit location context (e.g. `X-Map-Viewport` header) to focus on a smaller bounding box - you would get results spread all over your country.

If you can live without the "places", and only need streets, you can use the Geocoding API - with that one you can soft or hard filter the results by country.

Places and Geocoding seems to be two very distinct pieces of software, there is little to no cohesion between the two APIs

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the geocoder api?  it is what I use for my "autocomplete suggestion" input fields and you can limit suggestion results to a bounding box and specify the exact state.  It will also tell you what the location type is for every result, as well as more detailed information.

For example:

https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?mapview=16.6,-170.2;76.0,-45.4&state=wa&searchtext=2021&gen=9&app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&size=10

I have not used the places api, but it sounds like the geocoder will also meet your requirements.